# Group by multiple columns, get group total count and specific column from last two rows in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server table with the following columns:

```
Notification
===================
Id (int)
UserId (int)
Area (int)
Action (int)
ObjectId (int)
RelatedUserLink (nvarchar(100))
Created (datetime)
```

The goal is to create a query that groups notifications of the same **Area**, **Action** and **ObjectId** for a specific user (**UserId**) and
returns a single row including **total count for the group** and also the **value of a specific column for the last two rows**.

The query will only be executed for one user (**UserId**) each time.

The problem is that I need the column **RelatedUserLink** for the last two records (based on **Created**) of each group. The **RelatedUserLink** should be distinct for each group (if there are more than one, only the latest should be included and counted).

The **result for each group** should be represented in **one result-row**. It doesn´t matter if the two RelatedUserLink-values are concatenated in the same column or separated in two columns as "RelatedUserLink1" and "RelatedUserLink2". If the group only consists of one result the second RelatedUserLink should simply be null.

Desired result:

```
UserId | Area | Action | ObjectId | RelatedUserLink1 | RelatedUserLink2 | Created (latest in group) | Count 
10         1      2         100         "userlink1"       "userlink2"       2016-04-08                 20
10         1      3         200         "userlink1"       "userlink2"       2016-04-09                  4
```

The table will be quite large, 100.000-200.000 rows.
(The related User-table has approx 10.000 rows)

I also have the option to get all notifications for a user and then do the grouping in code but I hope there is a faster way by letting SQL server handle it!?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attempt this by using the following `WITH` clause:

```
WITH RUL AS (
select
  UserId,
  Area,
  Action,
  ObjectId,
  RelatedUserLink as RelatedUserLink1,

  LAG(RelatedUserLink) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Area, Action, ObjectId ORDER BY Created) as RelatedUserLink2,

  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Area, Action, ObjectId ORDER BY Created DESC) latest_to_earliest,

  MAX(Created) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Area, Action, ObjectId) as Created,

  COUNT(*) OVER OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Area, Action, ObjectId) as Count

from
  Notification
where UserId = 10
)
select 
  UserId,
  Area,
  Action,
  ObjectId,
  RelatedUserLink1,
  RelatedUserLink2,
  Created,
  Count
from 
  RUL 
where 
  latest_to_earliest = 1;
```

The `LAG` function will always hold the previous `RelatedUserLink` value (unless there is only one value in the group, which means it will be `NULL`). The `ROW_NUMBER` counts down through the group in `Created` order until it reaches 1 at the last row. The `MAX` and `COUNT` functions keep the maximum and count values for the entire group on each row, effectively the same as a `GROUP BY`, eliminating the need to perform a separate query and join back.

The `SELECT` outside the `WITH` clause just picks up the final row for each group, which should hold the last `RelatedUserLink` value in `RelatedUserLink1` and the penultimate (or `NULL`) `RelatedUserLink` value in `RelatedUserLink2`.

Comment: Really nice, thanks! And it´s quite fast when you limit the query to a specific user.

Just to make sure, I guess the last where-clause should be:
`where latest_earliest = 1 and UserId=x` ?

Comment: Are there any indexes I can add to increase the performance even more?

Comment: Put the `UserId` where condition within the WITH clause to speed it up, and thanks for pointing out the mistake with `latest_earliest`. I renamed it `latest_to_earliest` to explain better what it is, however you can call it whatever you like as it's not in the final output.

Comment: Hi again, I just realized that if there are two identical notifications from the same related user `RelatedUserLink` (same area, action etc except for Created) they will be counted separately and also in some cases the `RelatedUserLink1` and `RelatedUserLink2` will contain the same user link. Is it possible to make the query only account for the latest distinct value of RelatedUserLink? (Or maybe, I could introduce an int that represents the related user id) Goal is to count those notifications from the same related user as 1 no matter how many they are. Should I create a new question?